# Remove the repeated values of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

1.**Input**: I have a dictionary list

```
{'1': [['a','b','c'],['f1','f1','f2']]}
```

2.**Expected Result**:

```
{'1': [['a','b','c'],['f1','f2']]}
```

3. I want the repeated values of nested dictionary be removed and only unique values be kept in the dictionary.

4.Code I tried:

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame(df)
df_d= df_t[(x.values())].drop_duplicates()
df_d
```

**Error**:
KeyError: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: if you do not mind the data type change and the possible order loss, convert the inner `list`s to `set`s. The duplicates will be automatically removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map and a custom function to solve this,

Define the function to drop dupes like this,

```
def remove_dupes(l):
    return [list(set(item)) for item in l]
```

And use this a map over the dict like this,

```
d = {'1': [['a','b','c'],['f1','f1','f2']]}
dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], remove_dupes(x[1])), d.items()))

# output: {'1': [['a', 'c', 'b'], ['f2', 'f1']]}
```

Comment: `list(map(set, l))` will be an alternative too

Comment: @Anonymous but that will change the dtype of the inner lists to set.